# Timer in JAVA has incorrect behavior for repeated tasks

Tags: android, timer, scheduled-tasks, timertask

I am using Timer to schedule 3 tasks periodically using scheduleAtFixedRate(). I start these 3 tasks in separate AsyncTasks at the same time.

```
poll_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task_polling, 0, 5*60*1000);
```

The result is that tasks are executed as per the schedule for some time. But later the tasks are not triggered based on the schedule (5 mins). After an hour, I observe multiple triggers of these tasks within difference of 20 ms.

Please advice how should I run my tasks always at the scheduled rate.

Code:

```
private void createPollingAsynctask(){
    polling = new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            setPollingTimer();
            return null;
        }
    };
}

 private void setPollingTimer() {
    if(task_polling != null){
        logi("Polling::Cancel old schedule");
        task_polling.cancel();
    }

    createPollingAction();
    poll_timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task_polling, 0, 5 * 60 * 1000);

        }
private void createPollingAction(){
    task_polling = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent alarmAction = new Intent("action");
            sendBroadcast(alarmAction);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: can you share the async tasks and the timer listener/receiver?

Comment: `Timer` is not an Android class.  It's only included in the API to support legacy Java libraries.  You should almost certainly be using a `Handler` in a `Service`.

Comment: I need to schedule a task periodically. I would need some API that could do that.

Comment: You could also use an [alarm](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html).

Comment: Kevin, I was originally using Alarms. But that too does not seem to work accurately. Everytime it is off by 1 minute or so.

Comment: You can still use a Handler and have the implementation of the handler simply schedule the next run when the current one completes.  That will be the same as a repeating task - you just have to write the code to do the repeating.

Comment: Hi Doug. I am not sure how Handler will handle time based repeating event. For example: I want to run a task every 5 minutes, so how should I do time check with the help of a handler. Could you please elaborate on it?